# Regex for accepting greek characters with tone char(')

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

i'm trying to find a regex for allowing only greek characters to pass. But as you know greek language supports an emphasis tote for the most worlds:

For example the world χρήμα which means money has ' character above η
How to detect this char with a regex? My current regex is this:

```
/^[\sΑ-Ω0-9α-ω!$@#*+=._%,-/]*$/
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a character class such as

```
[\u0370-\u03ff\u1f00-\u1fff]+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/7DZI71/1).